# Making a custom DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I would like to create a custom WPF DataGrid that includes a custom context menu as well as some custom key bindings. It needs to be some kind of custom control since we will have many instances of the same datagrid.

So far I have the following:

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    static MyDataGrid()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyDataGrid)));
    }
}
```

And in the Themes folder, I have MyDataGrid.xaml which contains:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Paste" Command="{Binding PasteCommand }" />
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="Insert" Command="{Binding InsertCommand }" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand }" />
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="Move Up" Command="{Binding MoveUpCommand }" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Move Down" Command="{Binding MoveDownCommand }" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

However, when I create an instance of my control, it's just blank.

```
<custom:MyDataGrid
    ItemsSource ="{Binding MyObjects}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserResizeColumns="True"  
    ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader" 
    CanUserResizeRows="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"     
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    EnableRowVirtualization="False">

    ...

</custom:MyDataGrid>
```

What am I doing wrong? This is the first time I've tried to create a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

In resource dictionary you should provide `default template` for your custom control but you haven't provided any and moreover you want to provide context menu on default style so what you can do is base your style on dataGrid like this so that it `inherits template of dataGrid` -

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyDataGrid}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    ...
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the columns for brevity. They are there. What I mean by blank is that the control is completely blank, no columns, headers, nothing, just an empty white canvas.

Comment: Have you replaced `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"` with actual namespace where your control exist?

Comment: Yep. Everything is correct as far as I can tell. I tried a clean/rebuild, but still the same thing.

Comment: Strange. It's working for me in small sample. You gotta be missing something most likely the namespace. Make sure `local` is same as `custom` namespace which you are using at instance declaration.

Comment: Also make sure `TargetType` and `BasedOn` is set properly like i provided in sample above on your default style.

Answer (score 0):

If you've override the default style you must specify a control template for your Custom DataGrid ,

ether loose this line :

```
  DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyDataGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyDataGrid)));
```

Or specify a ControlTemplate .

1) Edit a copy of the DataGrid in Expression Blend [Like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295021.aspx)

2) [Or copy paste it from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Is this seriously the only way to modify the default template? This seems absolutely terrible.